# GD multiple image manipulation, how to handle memory error?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, gd

I have some images in a mysql database stored as BLOB's.

The maximum file size of the images is 5MB.

I am trying to create thumbnails of the images, using php GD.

I am using the script below:

```
include 'models/connectdb.php';

// ------ starting up ------ //

$directory = 'views/images/generated/events/xs/';
$table = 'events';
$dimension_x = 50;
$dimension_y = 50;


// ------- proccess ------- //

//$query = "ALTER TABLE $table ADD thumb0 VARCHAR(100);";
//$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table;";
$result = mysql_query( $query ) or die(mysql_error());
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $uploaded_image = base64_decode( $row['image'] );
    $uploaded_image = imagecreatefromstring( $uploaded_image );
    $uploaded_x = imagesx($uploaded_image);
    $uploaded_y = imagesy($uploaded_image);
    do{
       $filename = random_32();
       $filename = $directory.$filename.'.jpg'; 
    } while( file_exists($filename) );
       $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $dimension_x , $dimension_y );
       imagecopyresampled( $thumb , $uploaded_image , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , $dimension_x , $dimension_y , $uploaded_x, $uploaded_y);
       imagedestroy( $uploaded_image ); // I also tried unset( $uploaded_image );
       imagejpeg( $thumb , $filename , 90);
       $query = "UPDATE $table SET image_xs = '$filename' WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1;";
       mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
       echo "ran for one , ";
    }
echo "it all ran";

function random_32() { // this function generates a random filename
    $filename = rand( 100000000000000000 , 999999999999999999 );
    $filename = md5( $filename );
    return $filename;
    }
```

What I am getting is:

```
ran for one ,
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14032 bytes) in /home/leagu11/public_html/nightscene.gr/create_thumbs_people.php on line 21
```

Meaning my script runs for one image and dies before running for the next one.

I think I am doing something wrong with unsetting / destroying my data after each loop execution.

Any ideas?

Comment: The source image's file size means very little. What's its resolution? remember that internally the image has to be decompressed into a raw bitmap, which means at LEAST 3 bytes per pixel, 4 if you're using Alpha channels. That means a 1600x1200 alpha image = 7.6 megabytes of memory just to hold it for processing. 5MB means nothing, as it could be a low-quality jpg that's actually 10,000x10,000 = ~400 megabytes decompressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ini_set the allowed memory size for the runtime of the current script using `ini_set('memory_limit','128M');` But i have a feeling there might be something deeper hiding there.

Comment: Well, actually i've just ran across it and it looks pretty solid. You shouldn't be worried about it that much , Its very common that PHP scripts that manipulate images chug alot of RAM, as long as your server isn't too bad, a 128M or even a 2G limit for certain things isn't a bad thing at all :)

Comment: Also , you could save your dataset to a variable and then use `mysql_free_result` to free up some more ram, if your data set is large. Check out the example here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php

Answer (score 0):

While increasing memory available to the script isn't bad idea and indeed may be needed, I'd like to point out you are destroying only $uploaded_image. You should also destroy $thumb

That said, I experienced weird things with imagedestroy() myself and I'm not that sure it does all the job it's expected to. See [my question on imagedestroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320212/why-gd-doesnt-release-memory-upon-imagedestroy). Still, it seems to help in loops, so try it.