# Why GD doesn't release memory upon imagedestroy()?

Tags: php, memory, gd

I need a PHP CLI script to do various image transformations via GD functions. The images are quite big so I need to squeeze as much memory as possible. However, imagedestroy() seems not to release memory when asked.

Consider following demo script 'test.php':

```
    #!/usr/bin/php5
    <?php

    $memory = [0=> memoryCheck()];
    $res1 = imagecreatetruecolor(8192, 4096);
    memoryReport('Res1 created');
    $res2 = imagecreatetruecolor(8192, 4096);
    memoryReport('Res2 created');
    imagedestroy($res1);
    memoryReport('Res1 destroyed');
    imagedestroy($res2);
    memoryReport('Res2 destroyed');

    // memory reporting functions follow:
    function memoryCheck()
    {
        return (int) trim(substr(shell_exec('free -b'), 166, 11));
    }

    function format($value)
    {
        $val = \abs($value);
        $unit=array('B','kiB','MiB','GiB','TiB','PiB');
        return @round($val/pow(1024,($i=floor((($val==0)?0:log($val,1024))))),2).' '.$unit[$i];
    }

    function memoryReport($msg)
    {
        global $memory;

        $start = $memory[0];
        $prev = end($memory);
        $now = memoryCheck();

        echo sprintf("%s: %s (%s)\n", 
                        $msg, 
                        format($now-$start), 
                        (($diff=$now-$prev) <0) ? '-'. format($diff) : '+'. format($diff)
                    );
        $memory[] = $now;
    }
    ?>
```

Let's run it by issuing:

> free -m;./test.php;free -m

Example results:

```
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Mem:          7890       7072        818        561        218       2497
    -/+ buffers/cache:       4355       3534
    Swap:         8299          0       8299
    Res1 created: 109.76 MiB (+109.76 MiB)
    Res2 created: 218.77 MiB (+109.01 MiB)
    Res1 destroyed: 218.9 MiB (+140 kiB)
    Res2 destroyed: 888 kiB (-218.04 MiB)
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Mem:          7890       7072        817        561        218       2498
    -/+ buffers/cache:       4356       3534
    Swap:         8299          0       8299
```

As you can see, creating one image costs 109-110MB. After creating second one we have double that used up. But destroying first doesn't release memory. All the resources' memory gets released only after both images are destroyed.

Why? Have I overlooked something? What should I do to amend it?

UPDATE:
I added setting $res1 to null and then unsetting it altogether. Code:

```
    $memory = [0=> memoryCheck()];
    $res1 = imagecreatetruecolor(8192, 4096);
    memoryReport('Res1 created');
    $res2 = imagecreatetruecolor(8192, 4096);
    memoryReport('Res2 created');
    imagedestroy($res1);
    memoryReport('Res1 destroyed');
    $res1 = null;
    memoryReport('Res1 is null');
    unset($res1);
    memoryReport('Res1 is unset');
    imagedestroy($res2);
    memoryReport('Res2 destroyed');
```

Now result is:

```
    Res1 created: 109.48 MiB (+109.48 MiB)
    Res2 created: 219.33 MiB (+109.85 MiB)
    Res1 destroyed: 219.5 MiB (+168 kiB)
    Res1 is null: 220.15 MiB (+668 kiB)
    Res1 is unset: 220.38 MiB (+232 kiB)
    Res2 destroyed: 2 MiB (-218.36 MiB)
```

Also, I added

```
    gc_collect_cycles();
    memoryReport('GC collect');
```

right before imagedestroy($res2); and then things go strange:

```
    Res1 created: 109.59 MiB (+109.59 MiB)
    Res2 created: 219.08 MiB (+109.5 MiB)
    Res1 destroyed: 219.21 MiB (+132 kiB)
    Res1 is null: 219.36 MiB (+148 kiB)
    Res1 is unset: 219.75 MiB (+408 kiB)
    GC collect: 220.57 MiB (+836 kiB)
    Res2 destroyed: 220.46 MiB (-108 kiB)
```

According to 'free' command, the memory gets released only after script ended.

Comment: imagedestroy() will only free up the memory for use within PHP. It won't necessarily release the memory back to the system. PHP allocate memory from the system in blocks. A block used by $res1 won't get freed if it happens to contains stuff from $res2 (or any other variable). There's little you can do except to try changing the order of these resources' creation.

Comment: @cleong you should post this comment as an answer.

Comment: Indeed, please do it so that I could reward your answer :)

Comment: @cleong: please post your comment as answer so that I could reward your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's GC... try running `gc_collect_cycles()` after `imagedestroy()`. Long shot, but you never know...

Comment: See updated question. Adding this gc_collect_cycles() actually made things worse. I'm even more confused.

Comment: Hmm... sorry, I'm out of ideas. Good luck!